# How to detect Dynamic Font size changes from iOS Settings?

Tags: ios, uifont

Inside settings->general->text size, after changing the text size, I'd have to exit my own app to have the sizes applied to

```
 [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:..]
```

Is there a delegate or notification to notify my app to re-apply the new sizes?

Update: I tried the following but interestingly, the font size will apply after I BG and launch the app TWICE.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fromBg:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

}


 -(void) fromBg:(NSNotification *)noti{

    self.headline1.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
    self.subHeadline.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline];
    self.body.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
    self.footnote.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleFootnote];
    self.caption1.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1];
    self.caption2.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption2];
//    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You listen for the Size Change Notification on [UIContentSizeCategory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategory).

*Swift 3.0:*
`NSNotification.Name.UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange`

*Swift 4.0 or later:*
`UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification`

Comment: Ok but what do I do to apply the new font sizes?  Do I set the fonts to the preferredFontForTextStyle again?

Comment: @mskw yep, that's all you need to do.

Comment: Have issues in Swift 4.2 with adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory not working, the notification always works.

Answer (score 74):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12, you can choose one of the **three following solutions** in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting`'s `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` property

`UILabel`, `UITextField` and `UITextView` conform to `UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting` protocol and therefore have an instance property called [`adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategoryadjusting/1771731-adjustsfontforcontentsizecategor). `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` has the following declaration:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the object automatically updates its font when the device's content size category changes.

```
var adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory: Bool { get set }
```

The `UIViewController` implementation below shows how to detect and react to dynamic font size changes in iOS settings with `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        view.addSubview(label)

        // Auto layout
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        let widthConstraint = label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint])
    }

}
```

---

### #2. Using `UIContentSizeCategory`'s `didChangeNotification` type property

`UIContentSizeCategory` has a type property called [`didChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategory/1622948-didchangenotification). `didChangeNotification` has the following declaration:

> Posted when the user changes the preferred content size setting.

```
static let didChangeNotification: NSNotification.Name
```

> This notification is sent when the value in the `preferredContentSizeCategory` property changes. The userInfo dictionary of the notification contains the `newValueUserInfoKey` key, which reflects the new setting.

The `UIViewController` implementation below shows how to detect and react to dynamic font size changes in iOS settings with `didChangeNotification`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        view.addSubview(label)

        // Register for `UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification`
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preferredContentSizeChanged(_:)), name: UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification, object: nil)

        // Auto layout
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        let widthConstraint = label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint])
    }

    @objc func preferredContentSizeChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        /* perform other operations if necessary */
    }

}
```

---

### #3. Using `UITraitCollection`'s `preferredContentSizeCategory` property

`UITraitCollection` has a property called [`preferredContentSizeCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1771746-preferredcontentsizecategory). `preferredContentSizeCategory` has the following declaration:

> The font sizing option preferred by the user.

```
var preferredContentSizeCategory: UIContentSizeCategory { get }
```

> With Dynamic Type, users can ask that apps display text using fonts that are larger or smaller than the normal font size defined by the system. For example, a user with a visual impairment might request a larger default font size to make it easier to read text. Use the value of this property to request a `UIFont` object that matches the user's requested size.

The `UIViewController` implementation below shows how to detect and react to dynamic font size changes in iOS settings with `preferredContentSizeCategory`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        view.addSubview(label)

        // Auto layout
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        let widthConstraint = label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint])
    }

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        if previousTraitCollection?.preferredContentSizeCategory != traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory {
            self.label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
            /* perform other operations if necessary */
        }
    }

}
```

---

Sources:

- [useyourloaf.com / Auto Adjusting Fonts for Dynamic Type](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/auto-adjusting-fonts-for-dynamic-type/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I couldn't find if there was a way to programmatically detect Larger Accessibility Sizes switch is turned on or off. Do you know if it can be done?

Comment: @Dave You can test it like that: `if traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory { /* ... */ }`. See [useyourloaf.com / Making Space For Dynamic Type](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/making-space-for-dynamic-type/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Imanou Petit 's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1966109/imanou-petit) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536515/2704776)

You can also do this to get the size:

```
let contentSize = traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory
if contentSize.isAccessibilityCategory {
   if contentSize >= .accessibilityLarge{
        print("larger than or equal to accessibility large")
    }else {
        print("lower than large")
    }
} else {

    print("not accessibility")
}
```

}